# Transfer html tags to specific characters

Tags: php

I'm trying to transfer the following HTML to a little bit tricky form using php, as shown below:

`<dd>abc<br />def<br />ghi</dd>`

↓

```
abc
def
ghi
```

Say `<dd>abc<br />def<br />ghi</dd>` is defined at `$strRet`. How can I use some combinations of `str_replace` and/or `preg_replace` functions to modify to the specific format?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: What have you tried? Because your suggestions sound good to me.

Comment: What you want to do? a) delete all html tags and transform to \n (or PHP end-of-line) ? b) transform <dd> to <br> ? c) transform to other format? ... which format?

Comment: @MateuszPalichleb : I can guess here that, he wants to convert from `String format` to `HTML format`

Comment: How you are echoing/output the above string ?

Comment: I wanted to make an output as a string.
Anatolii Bivol solved my problem.
Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that if you remove the `<dd>` and `</dd>` tags then your string should display the way you want it:

```
$output = str_replace(['<dd>','</dd>'],'',$strRet);
```

Then, if you want to get rid of the `<br>` tags and replace them with new lines:

```
$output = str_replace('<br />',"\n",$output);
```